# Read only SSCC from EAN-128 barcode

Tags: barcode, motorola, datawedge, gs1-128

We have a Motorola barcode scanner with datawedge installed. We use EAN-128 barcodes that contain only the SSCC. For GS1 compliance, the barcode also contains the application identifier ("00") because it is a SSCC (FNC code is included in the barcode).
At the moment, when we scan a barcode in a application, we get "00123456789123456789" (the "00" at the beginning are the application identifier for the SSCC) which cannot be processed by our application. We have to also support barcodes that are not SSCCs but look very similar: "000000009123456789" The "00" at the beginning are not applications identifiers (there is no FNC code in the barcode).

**Question**: Can the Datawedge software be configured to only extract the SSCC number -> "123456789123456789" without the application identifier while still supporting non GS1 barcodes that have leading zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataWedge can be configured to prepend the AIM symbology identifiers, ie:

- *GS1* will be decoded to `]C1...`
- Regular *Code 128* to `]C0...`
- *Code 39* to `]A0...`

Here you have a [full list](http://mdn.morovia.com/kb/AIM-Symbology-Identifiers-SI-10639.html).

That way, if you read `]C1...` you know you have to interpret the first two digits as an application code and if you read another code `]XX` you just eliminate the prefix and take the whole code.